# Email attachment from php memory file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to attach a file to an email using the code igniter email library. I'm trying to attach the file without actually writing the file to disc. I thought I could use a PHP memory file to accomplish this, but it't not working for me:

```
$file_content = implode("\n", $all_data);
$filename = 'php://memory/test.tsv';
$f = fopen($filename,'w');
fwrite($f, $file_content);
fclose($f);
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Message:  fopen(): Invalid php:// URL specified
```

Does anyone know why I would be receiving this error?  Could it possibly be a PHP version issue?  When I echo `phpversion()` I get the following output:  `5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11`